# Unexpected field ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, ng-file-upload

I'm new on AngularJS and I'm trying to upload an image with ng-file-upload

My task was to translate an Ionic app to a web app so I've to reused same routes.

```
<button ngf-select="upload($file)" ng-model="file">Select</button>


    $scope.upload = function (file) {
      $scope.event.headerPictures.push(file);
      console.log($scope.event);
      console.log(file);
      if (file && !file.$error) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: $config.baseUrl + '/api/event/upload-picture',
            method: "POST", 
            headers: {"Authorization" : "token=" + userService.getToken()},
            file: file,
        }).then(function (resp) {
            console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
        }, function (resp) {
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        }, function (evt) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
        });
      };
    };
```

I'm still getting the same error with many different syntaxe :

```
Error: Unexpected field
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing ?

Comment: Where the error come from? Which line? Is it after you upload before selecting etc?

Comment: Hi Danial, the error come from when the POST is done. I get it in the server console once the file has been send.

Comment: If the error is on the server then post your server code and it is probably not related to ng-file-upload plugin since it is just a client side library.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to guess in an answer but with an unexpected field error I would think the line of your code with the extra comma delimiter is the issue.

`file: file,` should be `file: file`

Hope this helps. I would have commented this but my reputation is too low for comments still :)